# Merge Json objects, regardless of Memory

Tags: php, json

OK, here's what I need :

- I've got several (*lots* of them actually) json objects written to files (e.g. `result.1.json`, `result.2.json`, etc)
- I need to combine all of them in an array, like :

  ```
  $results = array (
      json_decode(file_get_contents("result.1.json"),      
      json_decode(file_get_contents("result.2.json")), 
      ...
  )
  ```
- And then write all `$results` back to a json file, like :

  ```
  file_put_contents("results.json",$results);
  ```

---

And here's the issue :

1. if we are talking about **LOTS** of json objects, am I going to face a Memory limit error (that's why I decided to split the objects in the first place - storing all results in memory triggered a Memory related error and crashed)?
2. If the above is true, how could I circumvent it, and still "concat" the objects?

Comment: Give more details about files which you want to merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objects from the file(s) get enclosed in to just one big array, there's actually no need to read and decode them, assumed they actually are valid JSON Syntax.

An Array is of the kind:

```
[
    { obj1},
    { obj2}
]
```

So you can just do the following:

```
file_put_contents("results.json","[\n");
while ( ... has more files ... )
{
   file_put_contents(file_get_contents($theFile), FILE_APPEND);
   if ( .... has more files ....)
         file_put_contents("results.json",",\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
file_put_contents("results.json","]\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

This will use almost no memory and is quite fast.

Comment: Yep, that's one of the solutions I've guessed as well... ;-)

Comment: only missing 1 thing, it puts additional ',' at the end which breaks the json.

        $keys= array_keys($files);
        $last_key= end($akfiles);
foreach( $files as $k => $file ) {
....
            if ($k != $last_key) file_put_contents('results.json',",\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes/No/Maybe. It all depends on what is your `memory_limit` really and how much memory you need to process all your JSON.
2. Increase memory limit if you can; process offsite and put all json data in DB for smarter processing

Comment: Well, I've just applied the `memory_limit` trick; let's see how much this could help... :-)

Comment: Programmers rules: #1) any limitation will be exceeded. #2) Any assumption is wrong.